# Make an mysql to excel with foreach?

Tags: php, arrays, excel, foreach, download

I have a problem with the following code, when I load it the screen is white and I don't download the excel file, Im trying to make:

```
foreach($lists as $list)
{
    array($list[1], $list[2]),

}

<?php

// load library
require 'php-excel.class.php';

// create a simple 2-dimensional array
$data = array(


header('Cache-Control: no-cache');
header('Pragma: no-cache');
require_once "getlists.php";
$lists = getLists($month, $who);
if(!empty($lists))
{
    1 => array ('Name', 'Surname'),
    foreach($lists as $list)
    {
        array($list[1], $list[2]),
    }

        array('Test', 'Peter')
        );
}
        array('Schwarz', 'Oliver')


// generate file (constructor parameters are optional)
$xls = new Excel_XML('UTF-8', false, 'My Test Sheet');
$xls->addArray($data);
$xls->generateXML('my-test');

?>
```

I hope someone can help me out here bc im lost, and really don't know why this isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that you have PHP code outside of the PHP tags?

```
foreach($lists as $list)
{
    array($list[1], $list[2]),

}

<?php

...
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be looking at your PHP error log as there are a few syntax errors here.

Firstly, as joseph4tw said, you have some php code before the initial `<?php` tag.

I think your main issue is that you are trying to fill the `$data` array from inside code and that just isn't possible. Again warnings and errors would have let you know about this. What you should do is create the array up front and then append to it as you go through the code:

`$data = array(` should be `$data = array();`

`1 => array ('Name', 'Surname'),` should be `$data[] = array('Name', 'Surname');`

`array($list[1], $list[2]),` becomes `$data[] = array($list[1], $list[2]);`

And so on.

Comment: Sorry im new with stackoverflow :p I made mistake with the code part, I want to show that the fail was from this part: "foreach($lists as $list)
{
    array($list[1], $list[2]),

}

<?php"

Comment: Yep I suspected as much. The reason that code you pasted at the top is not working is because of the reasons I mentioned above. You need to change to creating an empty $data array up front then appending to it inside the foreach loop.

Comment: Is it even getting to the foreach? I suspect $lists = getLists($month, $who); is not returning what you expect so if(!empty($lists)) is failing and it never gets to the foreach.

Comment: Found out that I made a dummy mistake -.- was missing a "{"

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution on how to make a easy table, mysql, data to excel.

And I want to share my solution with all people ;)

```
<?php

// load library
require 'php-excel.class.php';

// create a simple 2-dimensional array
$data = array();
$data[] = array('Name', 'Surname');

header('Cache-Control: no-cache');
header('Pragma: no-cache');
require_once "getlists.php";
$month = 8;
$who = 18;
$lists = getLists($month, $who);
if(!empty($lists))
{
    foreach($lists as $list)
    {
        $data[] = array($list[1], $list[2]);

    }


}

$data[] = array('hej', 'hej');
print_r($data);




// generate file (constructor parameters are optional)
$xls = new Excel_XML('UTF-8', false, 'My Test Sheet');
$xls->addArray($data);
$xls->generateXML('my-test');

?>
```

excel php class not made by me...
http://pastebin.com/QSnLhz2u